Implement a Condition in an Azure AI Search Skillset
We are utilizing Azure skills to identify the language code and then perform OCR on documents with an unknown language code. Could someone provide guidance on how to implement this conditional code? I'm encountering errors and might not be applying it correctly.

You no need to do document extraction, by default the indexer does those things and gives the content and metadata in /document context.
For getting language code you can give the field name as
/document/metadata_language .
You pass this as inputs for conditional skill and do OCR for further improvement.
Alter you conditional skill like below.
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Util.ConditionalSkill",
  "name": "Language Check",
  "description": "Check if language code is 'Unknown'",
  "context": "/document",
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "condition",
      "source": "= $(/document//document/metadata_language) == '(Unknown)'"
    },
    {
      "name": "whenTrue",
      "source": "/document/normalized_images/*"  //here you can also use  /document/content
    },
    {
      "name": "whenFalse",
      "source": "= null"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "output",
      "targetName": "imagesForOcr"
    }
  ]
},

Note:  Make sure you give indexer configuration to exract content and metadata.
Below is the indexer definition.
{
  "@odata.context": "https://jgsaisearch.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DC91AC57C625BF\"",
  "name": "azureblob-indexer",
  "description": "",
  "dataSourceName": "ds",
  "skillsetName": "skillset1718943474465",
  "targetIndexName": "azureblob-index",
  "disabled": null,
  "schedule": null,
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": 0,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 0,
    "base64EncodeKeys": null,
    "configuration": {
      "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
      "parsingMode": "default"
    }
  },
  "fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "targetFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "base64Encode",
        "parameters": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputFieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/myLanguageCode",
      "targetFieldName": "lang_code"
    }
  ],
  "cache": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}

Output:


Hi @JayashankarGS I tried your way, It seems to be working but now the problem coming is extracted_content, I am getting null. Can you please help here, because if you see Edit2, I have included indexer & skillset json and debug session o/ps

Earlier I was thinking, maybe images are not in the imagesForOcr forlder but in debug session I checked images are there which means i may be expecting extracted_content at wrong place but I tried all these - /document/imagesForOcr/extracted_content and /document/extracted_content and /document/imagesForOcr/extracted_content/* i see null the only o/p

Of course you will get null values. Since you document  having unknown language. Try Check the condition for unknown language.

Hi @JayashankarGS I might missed something while explaining maybe.....here Goal was extracting content (from both known/unknown lag code pdf) when its unknown (meaning pdf was made up of images) then to extract content we need to use OCR because otherwise it will wont work next, when it's known then by default method how indexer does the extraction..whichever possible....this is my goal is
Earlier i achieved it using 4 step (Edit1) - DocumentExtractionSkill ->LangDetectionSkill -> ConditionSkil -> OCR, but I know this is not efficient.

Goal: Extract content in Both cases
.................When Unknown - use OCR to extract.................else, does it by default extract content like it extract lang. code?

ok. For the current code you have either you will get content if the language is de else null values. So, conditional skill is not useful here. So, my idea is first do ocr on all documents then pass /document/content, /document/imagesForOcr and /document/metadata_language to custom web api there you check the condition and return the values.

i can do that but the problem is i have these types of files appx. 100, rest 10000 have no issue. Just imagine how much increase in time will cost me if i do ocr on all 10100 files. Thats why i am just thinking of handling these through condition.

See what you are thinking of conditional skill is not correct. it either gives you the records satisfied else null. example you are having 100 ppx and in conditional skill it if the language is unknown or null then it gives the content of this 100 ppx  else null. here, you will only get content of 100 ppx and remaining 10000 is set to null.

Okay I understood, so is there any way without going for customwebskill?
@JayashankarGS

raised new question, right? will update there. i hope my solution reduced few steps regarding language code.

Yes, marked completed! @JayashankarGS

ok. Either me or community will give the solution.
